# CPU usage problem by MySQL In a WordPress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, mariadb

I have a WordPress site on digital ocean with following configuration

1. ubuntu 18 OS
2. mariadb
3. wordpress
4. php7.2-fpm

they are hosted on a 80$ droplet, A 4 core dedicated cpu droplet still my site goes DOWN, on checking graphs everything is normal i.e CPU usage is 20%, Disk at 50%, Memory at 33% but still site gives a 502 error during high traffic.

when i SSH into droplet and use Ubuntu’s command `htop` i see a single `mysql pid` using upto 200% CPU, is this a reporting problem ?

why all 4 core of my CPU is around 20-40% but a single pid of mysql is using 200% CPU internally and crashing the site and how can i fix it ?

> below is the screenshot of `htop` data

[image]

Comment: If you have 4 cores, then you have 400% CPU available (I think)

Comment: @RiggsFolly ... i am not a expert in this but even i think that should be the case but whats happening here ?

Comment: What does mongodb have to do with this server?  PID 1405 and 1414 running for 4h appears to be missing a CONNECTION close(). Could we use Skype TALK to sort this out?  Skype ID wlhauck@aol.com

Comment: @WilsonHauck .... i am also running a app server built with node and mongodb in same rig, anyways i found the issue and fixed, thanks

Comment: Could you give us a clue on the issue found and how you fixed it? Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck ...... there was a plugin called" wordpress popular posts" which was running unnecessary queries in database. found it using SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST command in mysql cli

Comment: @WilsonHauck ....alternately i also configured redis cache to reduce unnecessary load on mysql server. now mysql doesn't take anything more than 20% cpu

Comment: Thank you for the solution you implemented.